# MySQL can't create table

Tags: mysql

I can't see why I have a error, if someone can help that. That would be great thank you!

Here is my DB:

Executing SQL script in server
`ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'mydb.employee details' (errno: 121)`

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Employee Details` (
   `Unique_Employee_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
   `Unique_Cinema_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
   `Employee_Full_Name` VARCHAR(240) NOT NULL ,
   `Employee_Role` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
   `Employee_Email` VARCHAR(240) NOT NULL ,
   `Employee_Contact_Number` DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL ,
   `Gender` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL ,
   `Date_of_Birth` DATE NOT NULL ,
   `Employee_Address` VARCHAR(240) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Unique_Employee_ID`) ,
   INDEX `Unique_Cinema_ID_idx` (`Unique_Cinema_ID` ASC) ,
   CONSTRAINT `Unique_Cinema_ID`
   FOREIGN KEY (`Unique_Cinema_ID` )
   REFERENCES `mydb`.`Cinema Details` (`Unique_Cinema_ID` )
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to add a `constraint` with a name already used somewhere.

Change the name of `CONSTRAINT Unique_Cinema_ID` and it will works.

You can check in the `information_schema.table_constraints` if you don't believe me :).

Comment: @armillsx You're welcome :). Feel free to accept the answer if it was correct for you so other people having the same problem know it is right.

Comment: Just another question. The Unique_Cinema_ID is the foreign key on another of my tables and a primary key on the Cinema Details one. I don't know what to do because I need the foreign key in there. Thanks again if you can help! :)